# SharePoint 2013 and Bing map web part

Tags: sharepoint-2013, bing-maps

I have two questions:
1. On a SharePoint 2013 page the Bing map throws an error *Uncaught TypeError: Microsoft.Maps.Location is not a constructor* in the Chrome and the Firefox browsers. How can i fix it, please?
2. The Bing v7 migration to v8 will affect SharePoint 2013?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure which web part this is. The built in mapping functionality in SharePoint was wraps the Bing Maps API's and was built and is supported by the Sharepoint team. There was also a basic webpart I believe which the SharePoint or Office team created, but I believe this was deprecated a few years ago.

As for V7 migration, all v7 traffic now points to v8 as v8 is over 95% backwards compatible and majority of v7 apps were able to continue working with a simple redirect of the API.